AWS Cognito Identity Credentials for API Gateway
I am using a nodejs based lambda for my authentication and after the username & password login, I get the IdToken as the following, which is working my 'Authorization' Header for my other API Gateway requests
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ region: 'region' });
exports.login= async(username,password) =>{

  const params = {
      AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
      ClientId: 'ID'
      AuthParameters: {
        'USERNAME': username,
        'PASSWORD': password
                }
      }
  const data = await cognito.initiateAuth(params).promise();
  return {
        status: 200,
        data:{
               IdToken: data.AuthenticationResult.IdToken,
               refreshToken: data.AuthenticationResult.RefreshToken,
               expiresIn: data.AuthenticationResult.ExpiresIn,
             }
       }
}

So I am using also the Social Logins (Google) by getting google access token.
I have a SessionToken afterwards.
But it does not work with Authorization Header.
Can you help me about that?
exports.googleLogin = async(googleAccessToken) =>{

        const cognitoIdentityCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: "IdentityPoolId",
            Logins: {
                'accounts.google.com': googleAccessToken
            },
        });
        await cognitoIdentityCredentials.getPromise();
        const credentials = cognitoIdentityCredentials.data.Credentials


       //credentials has        accessKeyId, secretAccessKey,sessionToken

}

I need to find a way to get Id Token for Authorization Header
